# Cloudformation AWS::Batch::JobDefinition Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [LogConfiguration]]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

AWS CloudFormation UserGuide for AWS::Batch::JobDefinition says that there is LogConfiguration property. However when I try code bellow it gets error.

My CloudFormation code:

```
# AWS Batch Job Definition
  BatchProcessingJobDefinition:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      Type: container
      JobDefinitionName: 
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
          - '-BatchJobDefinition'
      ContainerProperties:
        Image:
          Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - Ref: AWS::AccountId
            - .dkr.ecr.
            - Ref: AWS::Region
            - '.amazonaws.com/'
            - 'batchjob-ecr'
            - ':latest'
        Vcpus: 2
        Memory: 2000
      LogConfiguration:
        LogDriver: "awslogs"
        Options: {
          "awslogs-region": "${MY_AWS_REGION}",
          "awslogs-group": "/aws/batch/custom/env-queue"
        }
      RetryStrategy:
        Attempts: 1
```

Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [LogConfiguration]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LogConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-jobdefinition-containerproperties-logconfiguration.html) is part of [ContainerProperties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-jobdefinition-containerproperties.html). So it seems your indentation is **incorrect**:

```
  BatchProcessingJobDefinition:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      Type: container
      JobDefinitionName: 
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
          - '-BatchJobDefinition'
      ContainerProperties:
        Image:
          Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - Ref: AWS::AccountId
            - .dkr.ecr.
            - Ref: AWS::Region
            - '.amazonaws.com/'
            - 'batchjob-ecr'
            - ':latest'
        Vcpus: 2
        Memory: 2000
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: "awslogs"
          Options: {
            "awslogs-region": "${MY_AWS_REGION}",
            "awslogs-group": "/aws/batch/custom/env-queue"
          }
      RetryStrategy:
        Attempts: 1
```

Comment: Thank you it solves the issue! Is LogConfiguration part of ContainerProperties? UserGuide shows LogConfiguration as seperate one.

Comment: @YerzhanKaskabay No problem. Its better to look and cloudformation docs.

Comment: I did the same mistake abnd from documentation it seems its part of job Definition